# Error in the query "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image][image]Hello in the below query I am facing an issues of "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." Can you please solve this error for me so that I can work on the query.

```
select
  substring(
    a.ProcessInstanceDescription, 
    charindex('http://', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ), 
    charindex('KeyInstr', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ) 
      - charindex('http://', a.ProcessInstanceDescription )), 
  c.StreamName AS Category,
  ProcessInstanceAppianID as jobId,
  a.ProcessInstanceName,
  a.ProcessInstanceTargetDate AS TargetDate,
  a.ProcessInstanceDescription as TaskDescription,
  b.Name as department,
  SUBSTRING(
    ProcessInstanceName, 
    NULLIF(
      PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',ProcessInstanceName),
      0),
    7) as code
from 
  InternalUseOnly..ProcessInstance a 
  join InternalUseOnly..Departments b 
    on b.KeyDepartment = a.KeyDepartmentEntered 
    AND b.updoperation < 2
  join InternalUseOnly..ProcessStream c 
    on c.KeyProcessStream = a.KeyProcessStream 
    and c.updoperation < 2
where 
  ProcessInstanceCompleted is null
  and a.KeyProcessStream in (330) 
  and a.updoperation < 2
```

I have attached an image above. I want to fetch only the URLs from the Task Description. Can you correct this query or give me an exact query to perform this same

Comment: can you make the query more readable?.. its a mess

Comment: Can you give us an example of your table records? Maybe the solution is in ProcessInstanceName wrong length...

Comment: I have edited the whole query for you

Answer (score 2):

Length parameter for SUBSTRING is always parameter #3.
Only when this parameter is <0 then this error occurs.
Which means that you have problems with first occurence of SUBSTRING, particulary this expression:

```
charindex('KeyInstr', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ) 
  - charindex('http://', a.ProcessInstanceDescription )
```

Probably you can't find `KeyInstr` in `ProcessInstanceDescription` field and this is why it fails.

How you can guard against this error depends on what you want to do.

**EDIT**

One way to deal with this is to check if your token has been found ('KeyInstr'). If not, substitute the result with desired value, be it 0, -1, NULL or something else that you need to signal an unexpected situation.

```
CASE 
  WHEN charindex('KeyInstr', a.ProcessInstanceDescription) != 0 THEN
    charindex('KeyInstr', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ) 
      - charindex('http://', a.ProcessInstanceDescription )
  ELSE 0 END
```

...or in your case it would be better to do...

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN charindex('KeyInstr', a.ProcessInstanceDescription) != 0 THEN
      substring(
        a.ProcessInstanceDescription, 
        charindex('http://', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ), 
        charindex('KeyInstr', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ) 
          - charindex('http://', a.ProcessInstanceDescription ))
    ELSE 0 END, 
  ...
```

Comment: Can you give me the whole query so that I can insert it and check whether I am able to get the unique column for URL or not

Comment: @Anoop: As Ozren said, *How you can guard against this error depends on what you want to do.* What do you want to do when `'KeyInstr'` is not found in `ProcessInstanceDescription`? I.e. what do you want to return as the result of SUBSTRING?

Comment: @Anoop: Also, if Ozren just gives you the whole query, will you learn anything?

Comment: I want to get the URL in the substring and return it in a different column with the name URL. Can you give me an exact query to acheive this ?

Comment: @Anoop: don't take it personally, but SO is not about coming to get instant solutions. Here you can find what is wrong with your query and one or several ways to fix it. I believe that this last edit can help you if you wish to do your work right.

Comment: @Anoop: You didn't get my question, did you? You are extracting the URL as a substring between the position of `'http://'` and that of `'KeyInstr'`. Now, what should be extracted if `'KeyInstr'` is *not found*? Because that (`'KeyInstr'` being not found) is what's happening in your case and causing the error. To solve the error, you should first decide how to act in the case that causes it. Honestly, why all this "give me teh codez" attitude, why not try to learn something?

Comment: Guys, it's all probably part of cultural, educational, professional and other differences. Yes, give-me-teh-codez is not a good way to learn anything. On the other hand, people should learn that it is so. StackOverflow is a great site to learn exactly this and people should not be driven away. Anoop, ask for something if you need it but please show some effort as well, it will be worthwile.

Comment: Well, I am not saying that giving someone a code snippet, or even a big bunch of code for that matter, is never helpful for learning things. But this is a bit different. I just doubt, from the absence of response from the OP other than "just give the complete query", that they are really going to learn something new. In fact, a solution to the problem is *already* present in their query, it is applied to the other SUBSTRING. Did that help/teach them?